Nuxtjs with Auth0 using module NuxtAuth for login with credentials
I want to log in a user with credentials using NuxtAuth at Aut0, but I didn't get it working....
//nuxt.config
runtimeConfig: {
  AUTH_SECRET: process.env.NUXT_AUTH_SECRET,
  public: {
    AUTH_ORIGIN: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ORIGIN,
  },
// error with authjs "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=%5BPOST%5D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdev-XXXXXX.eu.auth0.com%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Flogin%22%3A%20404%20Not%20Found"
 auth: {
    globalAppMiddleware: true,
    baseURL: runtimeConfig.AUTH_ORIGIN,
    provider: {
      type: "authjs", 
    },
  },
// error with local "Called endpoint with unsupported action login. Only the following actions are supported: providers, session, csrf, signin, signout, callback, verify-request, error, _log",

//changed path to signin results in this error "Invalid JSON body"
auth: {
  globalAppMiddleware: true,
  baseURL: "https://dev-XXXXXXX.eu.auth0.com",
  provider: {
    type: "local",
    endpoints: {
      signIn: { path: "/signin", method: "post" },
    },
  },

//api/auth/[...].js
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from "#auth";
const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
  secret: runtimeConfig.AUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
CredentialsProvider.default({
  async authorize(credentials, req) {
  const user = await $fetch(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin",
    //  "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login",
    //   "https://localhost:3000/api/auth/login",
    // "https://dev-XXXXXXXX.eu.auth0.com/api/auth/login",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password}),
    }
  )

//.env
...
NUXT_AUTH_SECRET="dummy"
NUXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ORIGIN="http://localhost:3000"
...

